# Lifting subgroups of $GL(n, p)$ to $GL(n, Z)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I'm trying to search the through the finite subgroups of $GL(n, Z)$.  Since each is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL(n, 3)$, I identify its subgroups, and then I want to lift them to $GL(n, Z)$. Or exclude them by proving they cannot be lifted.

Once I have the generators of a subgroup of $G(n, 3)$, I can lift the generators successively: modulo $3^2$ so that the relators are consistent, then modulo $3^3$ etc until multiplication modulo $3^k$ gives the same result as standard multiplication.

How do I deal with termination: will this always terminate or can it fail? Also, is there any other way of doing the lifting?

The subgroups I'm interested are groups of rotations that leave a lattice invariant.

Comment: Why would each finite subgroup of $GL(n,Z)$ be isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL(n,3)$?

Comment: There's a proof here: https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/finite-subgroups-of-gln-z/